# Python: How to pass blogspot warning page (guestAuth)

Tags: javascript, python, blogger, blogspot

I have written a python script to display blog pages and their properties.
This work pretty well except that some on blogspot which require manual validation on a warning page like this one:
http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html

So I don't know how to programatically validate to get to the page contents. 
The warnoing validation button has some URL like :
http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html?guestAuth='SOME VERY LONG ID'

Here is part of my current script printing image URLs (replace url variable with blogspot URL above):

```
import os, sys, urllib, httplib2, validators, time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()

status, response = http.request(url)

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')):
    print link['src']
```

How can I proceed to finally get to the page contents ?
How is this ID generated ?
Any example/information I could look at ?

Do I need to use GoogleAuth or google-auth-httplib2 for instance ? even if no google account is required to manaually get through.

I found nothing so far.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your issue is likely not the id but that the target page generates its content with javascript. Try disabling js in your browser and loading it, you'll see it doesn't show anything, id or not.

Comment: thank you for your input.
I disabled JS in firefox but the button still shows up.
In my case I only use a headless linux (there is no browser installed), only using python

Comment: The button shows up but the content of the target URL does not. So following the button link isn't going to get you anything without JS.

Comment: so I need to call JS from my python script, or before maybe ?
How can I do this ? Is there some JS module for python ?
or what would be teh basic syntax in JS to push that button ?

Comment: I think there are two things here. One is, if I understand it right, you're having trouble extracting the link from that button. That's a relatively straightforward thing you can look up. The other is, even if you did follow the link from the button, it's not going to give you the content of the blog unless you execute the JS on it.

Comment: Actually I want to validate that button in some way so that the default link http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html shows the real contents (not the warning page), then I can use my py script to display image properties... like it would do for blogs without that warning page. (I'm completely new to JS)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'validate the button'. The HTML that produces the button has the target link. All you have to do is parse it and follow the link.

Comment: Actually the webpage with the warning has the link as you said: <a class="maia-button maia-button-primary" href="http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html?guestAuth=.... but this is what I see in the debugger of my browser once the wanted page (http://ferdinandkreozot.blogspot.com/2015/12/busy-as.html) is replaced by the warning page. In my python script I don't see the same content in status or response variables. Also using wget will no get the content of this warning page....what JavaScript is executed here ? Thank you